# How to pass a CaseWhen variable as a parameter in Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala

In Scala I am modifying a DataFrame as below and have an expression as below:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(col("item_count"), when(col("item_count") == 10 , col("item_count") +  1).otherwise(col("item_count")))
```

Long story short, I want to allow the passing of a parameter via `condition_string` variable in the **when** statement.

```
val condition_string = lit("col('item_count') == 10")
val df2 = df.withColumn(col("item_count"), when(condition_string, col("item_count") +  1).otherwise(col("item_count")))
```

I have tried above, however, I am getting error: `Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException`

Are there any suggestions to implement this?

Comment: Do you need the condition to be defined as `String`? Why?

Comment: Why not `when(expr(consition_string), col("item_count") + 1).otherwise(...)`?

Comment: @GaëlJ, Yeah, as it is a property passed along as a string

Comment: @AminMal, thanks, however, tried it and getting an error that it is a "string" and not a "column"

Comment: @Techno04335 Did you notice the `expr` call? `expr` returns a column, not a string!

Comment: @AminMal, Looks like I did something wrong. Let me try again and comeback. Thanks!

Comment: @AminMal This is what worked for me: when(expr(s"${column} " +  condition) , WHERE I am allowing user to pass condition Example: (== 10) and column name Example: "item_count"

Comment: @Techno04335 great! I thought the whole expression is going to be passed through functions (including column name).

Answer (score 0):

As per @AminMal's comment. I utilized the `expr()` method.

This is what worked for me: when(expr(s"${column} " +  condition) , WHERE I am allowing user to pass condition Example: (== 100) and column name Example: "item_count" making the updated statement as below:

```
val column = "item_count"
val condition = "== 100"

val df2 = df.withColumn(col(column), when(expr(s"${column} " + condition), col(column) +  1).otherwise(...))
```